# Nuget packages are not published by clickonce

Tags: nuget, vsto, clickonce

The setup: 
 1. VS2017, Create Excel 2013 VSTO Add-in project 
 2. Nuget install: Snappy.NET 
 3. Right click => publish 
 4. check publish folder, there is no Snappy.NET.dll

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to install the packages through the packages.config file and not like project resources.

To try, uninstall all the Nuget pakages from project, save, exit and reopen the solution.

Check the "Allow format selection on first package install" option on Tools-> Options-> Nuget Pakage Manager -> General

Reinstall the packages.
Choose package.config file when Visual Studio asks which configuration to use

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your build process to have the target that would set Publish Status for all files from NuGet packages to Include instead of Prerequisite. Just add the following to your csproj.

```
<Target Name="IncludePackageReferencedFiles" BeforeTargets="_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo">
    <Message Text="Including files from NuGet packages for ClickOnce publishing" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <PublishFile
          Include="@(ReferencePath->'%(FileName)')"
          Condition=" '%(ReferencePath.NuGetSourceType)' == 'Package' and '%(ReferencePath.NuGetIsFrameworkReference)' != 'true'"
          KeepMetadata="None">
        <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
        <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
      </PublishFile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I have found it [here](https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras/issues/58).